# Will my Indian passport be stamped at Kuala Lampur airport while I'm transiting?

Tags: transit, passport-stamps, malaysia

Please assume the following:

1. I am travelling from Singapore to Bangalore transiting through Kuala
   Lampur.
2. I am an Indian national.
3. I will be travelling on one ticket.
4. I won't be leaving the airport.
5. I do not have check-in baggage.

Comment: Related but not identical: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153862/will-my-indian-passport-be-stamped-at-bangkok-airport-while-im-transiting

Comment: Are you asking if you’ll need to clear Immigration?

Comment: I'm just asking if there will be a malasian stamp on my passport.

Answer (score 2):

> Will my Indian passport be stamped at Kuala Lampur airport while I'm transiting?

No

See http://www.klia.com.my/transit/flight-transfers