# Will my Indian passport be stamped at Bangkok airport while I'm transiting?

Tags: transit, thailand, passport-stamps

Please assume the following:

I am travelling from Bangalore to Singapore transiting through Bangkok.
I am an Indian national.
I will be travelling on one ticket.
I won't be leaving the airport.
I do not have check-in baggage.

Comment: Related but not identical: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153859/will-my-indian-passport-be-stamped-at-kuala-lampur-airport-while-im-transiting

Comment: Are you asking if you can transit airside?

Comment: I'm just asking if there will be a thai stamp on my passport.

Answer (score 5):

If you're travelling on one ticket then your checked baggages will be forwarded directly by the airlines. Thus you'll be transiting airside and  won't have to clear immigration or customs. So there'll be no immigration stamps on your passport unless you plan to leave the airport and go visit Bangkok.

Source: Have transited through Bangkok several times